# ASP.NET Core AOP Interceptor HOW TO get ReturnValue from Async Method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, redis, aop, stackexchange.redis

I would like to get the value of Result which comes with invocation.ReturnValue , if it is not async , there is no problem. If the method is async, I cannot get the Result of it

```
    public class RedisCacheAspect: MethodInterception
    {
    private int _duration;
    private IRedisCacheManager _redisCacheManager;
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> TypeofTaskResultMethod = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
    public RedisCacheAspect(int duration = 60)//Default 60 
    {
        _duration = duration;
        _redisCacheManager = ServiceTool.ServiceProvider.GetService<IRedisCacheManager>();
    }

    public override void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var methodName = string.Format($"{invocation.Method.ReflectedType.FullName}.{invocation.Method.Name}");
        var method = invocation.Method;
        var arguments = invocation.Arguments.ToList();

        var key = KeyGenerator.GetCacheKey(invocation.Method, invocation.Arguments,"FoodThen");

        var returnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType;

        var isExists = _redisCacheManager.IsAdd(key);
        var isAsync = IsAsyncMethod(method);
        if (isExists)
        {
            string cacheValue = GetCacheAsync(key);
            var objValue = DeserializeCache(key, cacheValue, returnType);
            invocation.ReturnValue = ResultFactory(objValue, returnType, isAsync);
            return;
        }
        invocation.Proceed();
        _redisCacheManager.Set(key, invocation.ReturnValue,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_duration));

    }
```

DeserializeCache Method :

```
    private object DeserializeCache(string cacheKey, string cacheValue, Type returnType)
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cacheValue, returnType);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            _redisCacheManager.Remove(cacheKey);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

ResultFactory Method :

```
    private object ResultFactory(object result, Type returnType, bool isAsync)
    {
        if (isAsync)
        {
            return TypeofTaskResultMethod
                .GetOrAdd(returnType, t => typeof(Task)
                .GetMethods()
                .First(p => p.Name == "FromResult" && p.ContainsGenericParameters)
                .MakeGenericMethod(returnType))
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { result });
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

This is how invocation.ReturnValue looks like and I want to get the value of Result...

[image: ReturnValue image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you've debugged,have you noticed the value of returntype after `var returnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType;`  been executed?

For Async methods ,the return type  should be:

```
invocation.Method.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments.First();
```

Comment: With these method, I can get the return type of async method. But when the method is proceeded, returning value is async and I want to save the value not as an async type. The image above has 'Result' and I want to get it and then save it to Redis... this is all I need, do you have any idea about that ?